# search box with database

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, autocomplete

I am using  C#.net Windows form , and I need to create a search textbox which will display combo box values (similar to google search);
The values displayed in the combo box will be values from the SQL 2005 database (example the user is searching on FirstName, the combobox will display all firstnames, which get filtered as the user types in more letters.... if user is searching on LastName, the combo box displays all LastName values in the database.. etc)

Any ideas how to go about this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution from the web that does do what you desire but have the negative effect to load everything from the start instead of doing small queries.

```
List<string> namesCollection = new List<string>();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = 'Connexion String or From File'
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "Select distinct [Name] from [Names] order by [Name] asc";
conn.Open();
SqlDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dReader.HasRows == true)
{
   while (dReader.Read())
   namesCollection.Add(dReader["Name"].ToString());
}
dReader.Close();

txtName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
txtName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
txtName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesCollection;
```

Comment: ya but i have customised text box by the company, it does not hav the option auto complete mode. Is it possible with combobox, I mean when i am typing the first  letter in name it will shows all names starting with  that letter. would you pls help me out

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `AutoCompleteSource` property to `CustomSource`, then set the `AutoCompleteCustomSource` property to a collection of strings from your database.

Comment: i have known that thing. but i am not sure it wil works in windows form

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource.aspx

Comment: thanq slakhs ...but i have a doubt this works for string  fine but how to connect database

Comment: You need to connect to the database using ADO.Net and get your strings from it using a SQL command.